# grant admin's privilegies to domain group on MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, group-policy

Is it possible to grant admin's privilegies to domain group on MSSQL using Active Directory or vbscript? We have hundreds of MSSQL servers and we would automatically give access to domain group for each of them.

Comment: I have found good solution - http://serverfault.com/questions/346685/how-to-add-a-group-to-the-sysadmin-fixed-server-role-in-sql-server-2008-r2. But can there be another way?

Answer (score -1):

granting sysadmin role to built admin is not a good practice. In fact built admin group should be disabled as a best practice to secure your environment. I would recommend to create a new group in your AD and add this group on your servers with SysAdmin role. You can definitely achieve by a simple powershell script.